# QRCode generated in python

Tags: python, qr-code

I wrote some code to generate qrcode in python but at run time it shows this error:
Import "qrcode" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

I am using the qrcode library but I am having some problems.

Comment: How to reproduce ? Can you put your code ?

Comment: import qrcode

class CreateQrcode:

    def create(self, testo):
        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
            box_size=20,
            border=4,
        )
        qr.add_data(testo)
        qr.make(fit=True)

        img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
        img.save('qrcode.png')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation is pretty straight forward via pip install. Run the following command to install python-qrcode and pillow.

```
pip install qrcode[pil]
```

Once you are done, continue installing OpenCV-Python with the following command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

If you intend to detect multiple QR codes in a single image, make sure that the opencv-python version is at least 4.3.0. Older versions do not come with the multi detection functionalities.

Add the following import declaration at the top of your Python file.

```
import qrcode
from PIL import Image
```

For basic usage, you can simply run the make() function to generate a QR Code based on your input text:

```
img = qrcode.make('Your input text')
```

You can utilize the QRCode class, which comes with a lot more controls and properties.

```
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
```

The next step is to call the add_data() function. Pass in the input text of your choice. Continue by appending the following code to generate a QR code with a white background and black fill.

```
qr.add_data('https://medium.com/@ngwaifoong92')
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white").convert('RGB')
```

You can save it in as an image file as follow:

```
img.save("sample.png")
```

Finally you can read this [paper](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-generate-and-decode-qr-codes-in-python-a933bce56fd0).